# Bathroom Vanity counter top storage

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, repair, wood, carpentry

I just assembled a Bathroom Vanity Base Cabinet (36 x 22). After assembling, I placed a separate Vanity countertop to test if its structurally sound (from a different company). It works well. I didn't feel like repacking the countertop in the box, hard to repack. My plumber will come by in a few weeks to install.

Question: is it okay to leave the vanity counter top on the base without silicone caulk adhesive for a couple weeks to store? Will it cause any structural, sound issues if its left on without any caulk? Its stored in a separate quiet area in my house.

[image]

Comment: Silicon caulk is sticky, but more for it not to move when leaning against it.  Your plumber will probably be quite happy with you.  It is the base that provides structure support.

Comment: I think you're fine for your temporary situation.  That said, regular silicon is not a good adhesive.  Countertops usually are attached with some kind of brackets as well ,usually "L" shaped.  The consequences of the top shifting could include a plumbing leak, so I would advise using 2 or more mechanical fasteners as well.  If you don't feel comfortable drilling pilot holes in stone, then Perhaps use a better adhesive.  3M 5200 is completely waterproof and has pretty good shear strength for a flexible adhesive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR Don't caulk until installed

The caulk does two things:

- Help secure the top to the base

That should only be an issue if you are moving this (easy fix: move the two parts separately) or if there is concern about pets, small children, etc. bumping into it and knocking the top off.

- Keep water from getting into the base

Definitely not an issue until installation.

In fact, caulking before installation would actually be a *bad* idea because you would lose the ability to make slight adjustments to the position of the top, which are often needed depending on various factors. In addition, the plumber may prefer, given the option, to work on some of the plumbing after setting the base in place but before putting on the top.

In general, I would consider caulking as pretty much the last step in the installation process.

Comment: I believe the question is, is it ok not to caulk it

Answer (score 3):

It is ok to rest a stone countertop loosely on a vanity base for a couple of weeks.  Harm should come to neither.  I'll take it a step further: If either of them is so flimsy that they cannot tolerate this treatment, it would be better to become aware of it now than after installation.

A warning:  If the uninstalled vanity is not level and the countertop is not uniformly supported, there may be spots where pressure on top could could break the counter.  So make sure it's flat, put in some temporary shims if that would help, and just don't sit on it or put heavy objects on it before it's properly installed.

Comment: yeah, I will probably rest it there for 4 weeks ,   as always if the vanity countertop rests on the base, )with or without silicone), and is not uniformly supported, it can create pressure,  so I'll make sure it rests evenly when I actually install also, thanks